# `Function` works asynchronously in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a function that makes buttons slide from right to left by assigning `css` to a button using javascript. It works fine when I call the `onclick` event to trigger that `function`. Function like this:

```
function btnToggle() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.btnClass').forEach(el => {
      if (el.style.marginRight === "250px") {
          el.style.marginRight = "0px";
      } else {
          el.style.marginRight = "250px";
      }
   });
    
   var btnID = document.getElementById('btn3');
   if (btnID.style.marginRight === "250px") {
       btnID.style.marginRight = "0px";
   } else {
       btnID.style.marginRight = "250px";
   }
}
```

And I have a `slideToggle` slide from right to left that is automatically `expanded` on the web page reload by another function. I put it inside the function automatically expanded for `slideToggle` so that it fires automatically the `css` i assign to the `button` but it works asynchronously, only `btnID`  is active, `.btnClass` is still in place :

```
function anotherFunction() {
   ......
   btnToggle();
}
```

I think the error is caused by `forEach` but haven't found a fix yet, for some reason I can only use `class` for some buttons but cannot use their `id` for btnToggle() function. How can they work together or anchor them to the `div element` of the `slideToggle` function so that when `slideToggle` is activated manually or automatically they will slide along.

[This is my `slideToggle` slide from right to left if you need to see](https://jsfiddle.net/dyorLnuq/1/)

Comment: There is no `btnToggle` function in your link

Comment: I'm updated my link, sorry for the omission

Comment: @Jayzz I am not aware of the exact reason but, it's not because of functions instead its because of the placement of button tags in HTML, 
If you define this 

<button id="btn_id">button 1</button>

just after another button, then it works fine.

Comment: @ShubhdeepChhabra Unfortunately I can't directly interfere with the HTML and change the position of the buttons

Comment: "*I think the error is caused by…*" - what error are you getting?

Comment: @Bergi code in `forEach` that uses `class` works asynchronously with code that uses `id` (btnID). But that's just my speculation, because when I call the function of `btnToggle()` in another function only `btnID` works (slide from right to left) `.btnClass` is still in place

Comment: @Jayzz Nothing in the code you posted is asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi As I said in the question it works fine only when calling the `onclick="btnToggle()"`  event. But I have another function that can automatically expanded element `slideToggle` when reload website, I want it to be active with that function and not just using the `onclick`  event, so i called `btnToggle()` inside `anotherFunction()` and just button ` btnID` works (slide right to left)